# How to start an app with Activity1 or Activity2?

Tags: android, android-activity

I don't know how to implement this situation.
I have an app, during the start of the app, I need to calculate something and then, based on the results, start or Activity1 or Activity2.
How can I achieve this goal?
If I put the calculations in Activity1, and the calculations wants to start Activity2, however Activity1 starts Activity2 and then suddenly `finish()`, but the screen flickers because there is an activity that starts and ends in a few msecs. This is not very smart.

Comment: Why not have Activity 3, which is a splash screen, and do the work there. This is quite smart ;O), if your app takes some time to load/decide what to do. Remember also that you need to decide what to do if the app is paused (back to start screen ?).

Comment: jon goodwin please answer

Comment: This link will help to implement a splash screen in right way. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: [The (Complete) Android Splash Screen Guide](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565)

Comment: you must have activity 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a splash **activity** , and put your calculations there , and then based on the result you start the **activity** you want to

Answer (score 0):

Many ways you can do that. Let me share you one example given as follows

1. Create New activity ( StartActivity ) which is your root activity.
2. Within this activity initialize some object like ( App Config, fabric, push notification, share preference data  etc.)
3. Here you can calculate your necessary data and pass using bundle
4. Create Intent Object for translation to Activity1.class

   ```
   if(BuildConfig.DEV_ENV && CounterPreference.getInstance().isFirstStart()) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,  Activity1.class);
     startActivityForResult(intent, DEBUG_OPTIONS_ACTIVITY);
   } else {
      StartupManager.getInstance().start(StartActivity.this);
      Logger.d(TAG, "Application Started.....*************************");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Add your calculation in **Application** class *onCreate()* method.And Add your activity decision in Application class.

Comment: No, this is a bad answer. Android needs to start from an activity.